# How to ignore "Could not find a declaration" error in VS Code and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsconfig

I'm working with Typescript and Vue Cli using VS Code. I'm getting a "definition missing warning" at this line:

```
 import { setupCalendar, DatePicker } from "v-calendar";
```

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'v-calendar'.

This error does affects tsc compilation, but VS Code is always showing this error at the code and at the navigation bar

[image]

What Can I do in order to dismiss this error and get my "no error" status back ?

PS: `v-calendar` has no definition, it is a third part imported module.

PS: Here are my "tsconfig.json"

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": ["webpack-env", "mocha", "chai"],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    },
    "lib": ["esnext", "dom", "dom.iterable", "scripthost"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue", "tests/**/*.ts", "tests/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Is v-calendar a file defined in another location?  You can use relative paths to identify the location of the file that way.  Or is it a node module?

Comment: no, there is no definition, it is a third part imported lib

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'v-calendar'.

Create a file `external.d.ts` with the following

```
declare module 'v-calendar';
```

## More

[Some docs on migration including declaring existing modules](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/migrating)

Comment: Link is broken.