# How to disable typescript-related warning displayed by vscode in js-file which is not included in tsconfig?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Suppose I start with an empty directory and execute the following command to bootstrap a fresh project with a minimal setup to reproduce this:

```bash
npm install --save-dev typescript eslint eslint-config-airbnb-typescript
```

After that I open the project in vscode, and add `.eslintrc.cjs` with the following content:

```js
/* eslint-env node */
const eslintConfig = require("eslint-config-airbnb-typescript/lib/shared");
// does not matter what I do with eslintConfig
```

Here on a 2nd line vscode will underline the beginning of `require` argument to denote a warning and if you hover mouse pointer on it, you will get:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'eslint-config-airbnb-typescript/lib/shared'. '/Users/user/projects/ts-error-in-js-file/node_modules/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript/lib/shared.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'eslint-config-airbnb-typescript/lib/shared';`ts(7016)
```

Visually it looks like this:

[image: ts-related warning]

Notice that `ts(7016)` is a TypeScript compiler error. But why is this inspection applied to js-file?

My first thought is that I probably need to exclude the file from `tsconfig`, so I generate one with `npx tsc --init` and explicitly `exclude` this file. I can make sure that my exclusion worked out by trying to execute `npx tsc` and observing no complains on that file. Unfortunately, this nasty little warning in vscode does not disappear.
After googling the problem I found this [similar old question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51069070/3581539) and answers to it suggest to adjust vscode settings as follows: `"javascript.validate.enable": false`.
This options indeed removes the warning, but it will also disable TypeScript-related inspections on ANY js-files, which is not what you want in case when you have a mixed codebase with `"allowJs": true` and `"checkJs": true` in your `tsconfig`.

Is there a proper way to disable such ts-inspections for js-files which are not-included in the context with `tsconfig`?

Comment: note that this is a "quick fix" suggestion, and not a "problem" in VS Code terminology

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to ignore "Could not find a declaration" error in VS Code and TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54136015/how-to-ignore-could-not-find-a-declaration-error-in-vs-code-and-typescript)